# PHP Array before element and after element

Tags: php, nlp

I have a string and I change it into an array like this:

```
$a = "adik melempar kail ke tengah danau"
```

Array :

```
[0] => adik 
[1] => melempar
[2] => kail 
[3] => ke 
[4] => tengah 
[5] => danau
```

I have marked `array[1] => melempar` as verb (kata kerja).

How do I mark the next array (after `array[1]`) as object and the previous array (before `array[1]`) as subject?

An english example might be:

```
$a = "brother throw hook to the lake"
```

Array :

```
[0] => brother 
[1] => throw
[2] => hook
[3] => to 
[4] => the 
[5] => lake
```

Comment: Sorry, but I totally don't understand what you want. Your question is related to linguistics: what do you mean "mark as object" and "mark as subject"? Can you give an example in English, so everybody could understand your requirement.

Comment: ya, I just want give a simple question as an example, this is linguistic, but mine is so simply, yes like that you said, mark as object and mark as subject. "brother throw hook to the lake" thank's  @user4035

Comment: To be clear, you're saying that you have a code that already identifies which word in the sentence is the verb, and you want to get the index of the items before and after so that you can mark them as the subject and object (grammatically speaking). Do I have you right? Whether I do or not, adding your code would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you going to loop through the array looking for verbs? Assuming you have an array index variable $index, you could generally do something like this:

```
$words = explode(" ", $theSentence);
$index = 0;
foreach($words as $key=$theWord){
// apply your logic here that determines whether word is a verb
    if isVerb($theWord){
        $arrayResult[$index] = "verb";
        if($index > 0){
            $arrayResult[$index - 1 ] = 'subject';
            arrayResult[$index + 1 ] = 'object';
        }

    }
}


...
```

This is all very general, of course, since I don't know the context. You seem to have some logic in mind to determine what the words on either side of the verb are.

Comment: Could you give an example with an array please ? Thank's @Jack Albright

Comment: @nurharyadi, I changed my example code a little. This is obvously a very rough draft, and I'm not at all sure what sort of linquistic logic you are applying, or if you are simply doing this by manually.